# nginx mixing cached content between my different domains

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, cache

I don't know if this is a bug or I am defining cache incorrectly, I have a nginx cache (reverse proxy) server that is used by 2 **different** domains (`mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`), different content, not an alias domain.

I defined a single cache, then defined the two domains/vhosts in nginx and set it to use that cache, both domains take their data from same source server, but they pass the different vhost to the source server so they take the right content.

Problem is that nginx seems to mix the cache on the two servers, accessing one home page shows cached homepage of the other.

Do I need a separate cache defined for each vhost ?

Shouldn't NGINX also associate a vhost with each request ? It seems to just associate a source server, port, etc.

This is the head of cached home page, showing that there is nothing to differentiate between the two vhosts:

```
KEY: http://source.example.com:81/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 00:54:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Expires: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 02:54:33 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=7200
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.13.35.2-0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

My NGINX cache settings:

```
proxy_cache_path /ramdisk/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_ramdisk_cache:512m max_size=3g
                     inactive=30d use_temp_path=off;



# defining domain 1
server {
    [...]
    server_name  mydomain1.com;

    location / {

            proxy_pass       http://source.example.com:81;

            proxy_set_header Host      mydomain1.com;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_cache             nginx_ramdisk_cache;
    }
}

# defining domain 2
server {
    [...]
    server_name  mydomain2.com;

    location / {

            proxy_pass       http://source.example.com:81;

            proxy_set_header Host      mydomain2.com;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_cache             nginx_ramdisk_cache;
    }
}
```

and on the source server (apache) I have my 2 vhosts defined like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerName mydomain1.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain1.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerName mydomain2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question like a weirdo;

In order for nginx to make a difference between same paths used by two urls (e.g `/`), it needs to use `proxy_cache_key`, which by [default](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=2.55268011.129501190.1580606348-1160844069.1578342746#proxy_cache_key) seems to be `$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri`, this doesn't work in my case, when two nginx domains take data from same source server (by sending a different host header), they would **both** end up using a key like this:

`KEY: http://source.example.com:81` 
(I understand $proxy_host is = source server)

Solution: [specify](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/#specifying-which-requests-to-cache) a `proxy_cache_key` that includes the current `$host`, not `$proxy_host`;

```
proxy_cache_key $scheme://$host$request_uri;
```